# How to add files to repository but ignore changes

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible with Subversion and TortoiseSVN to have a file added to the repository, but ignore any future changes that are made to it in the working copy?

I'm trying to avoid long lists of files in the commit dialog of TortoiseSVN that are changed but never need to be committed. They are generated/changed by when building but their changing contents is not of any interest.

The specific situation where this occurs with our development environment is with several .res files in the Jvcl libraries. If they are not in the repository a full build with finalbuilder (calling jvcl/install.bat) after a clean export from the repository, results in errors about missing .res files. But every build also recreates  a lot of .res files which i don't actually want in my repository

Comment: Couldn't you make the first commit, then add it to ignore, locally, after?

Comment: @TerryBarriff - ignored committed file does not disappear from **repo** and will appear on update

Comment: If files are builds-artifacts, they are not used|needed in development? Why in this case they are part of repo?

Answer (score 0):

Precommit hook with `svnlook changed` and some logic for checking presence of prohibited file in list

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it looks like a workable solution. But this will still result in the files showing up in the commit dialog of TortoiseSVN. Thats what i'm trying to avoid (edited the question to reflect this)